# Environment variable is not update

Tags: bash, environment

I try to set the $PATH reference to the current working directory, one machine work as expected, but another machine is not.

basically, I have set below line in `.bashrc`

```
export PATH=$PWD/bin:$PATH
```

if I move directory to `/123`, I expected that the $PATH will updated to `/123/bin:$PATH` but it isn't.

Are there anyway to make it read the current $PWD to use in $PATH?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following line in `~/.bashrc` to add `./bin` directory in PATH

```
export PATH=./bin:$PATH
```

Next you need to run in terminal `source ~/.bashrc` to affect the change.

Comment: `.` should be `./bin` if you reread their question.

Comment: @ThomasW. Thanks for correcting me, I am editing it. But at his first line he mentioned about current directory only. And never asked for `./bin/` in every directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be in the subdirectory `bin` of the current directory that is `./bin` so:

```
export PATH=./bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

The `PATH` variable is not automatically updated.  When you move a folder such as `/home/$USER/bin` to `/home/$USER/notbin` you'll have to manually update your `$PATH` environment variable.  That will fix the issue.

It may also help to manually update the full directory path you're adding to `$PATH`.  If your directory you're adding to `$PATH` is `/home/$USER/stuff/programs/someprogram/bin` then `$PWD` won't really help you that much.  Therefore, knowing where your stuff is stored, and putting in the full path, will make almost-certain that the correct directory ends up in the `$PATH` variable.  (since `.bashrc` is located in your `~` dir, `$PWD` inside of `~/.bashrc` will always be your home directory, when its called.)

Comment: Nice exhaustive explanation, +1 from me.